# "Extra argument in call" error when using zip() to iterate over multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I'm trying to iterate over multiple arrays then place everything into one other array.
This is my class that I'm going to loop into:

```
class Place {

var names = [String]()
var messages = [String]()
var latidudes = [Double]()
var longitudes = [Double]()

var locations = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
}
```

And this is my function:

```
private func placesArrayLoop() {

let CoffeeShopNames = ["aCoffee","bCoffee", "cCoffee"]
let messages = ["message0", "message1", "message2"]
let latitudes = [40.232320, 40.232321, 40.232322]
let longitudes = [-95.388069, -95.388068, 95.388067]

for (name, message, latitude, longitude) in zip(CoffeeShopNames, messages, latitudes, longitudes) {
    let place = Place()
    place.names.append(name)
    place.messages.append(message)
    place.latitudes.append(latitude)
    place.longitudes.append(longitude)

    }
}
```

It is giving me the error, "extra argument in call pointing to latitudes in the zip array line. I'm assuming it's a syntax error new to swift 3, but I've looked around and cant find how to fix it. But the code bellow works...

```
let strArr1 = ["Some1", "Some2", "Some3"]
let strArr2 = ["Somethingelse1", "Somethingelse2", "Somethingelse3"]

for (e1, e2) in zip(strArr1, strArr2) {
    print("\(e1) - \(e2)")
}
```

So now I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `zip()` function only takes two arguments (hence why your second example works).
http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/func/zip/

You are trying to pass it four arguments.

Comment: Ah, Thanks! Do you know of any way to do what I'm trying that will work?

Comment: @Joneaux I would suggest creating a struct that contains properties `name`, `message`, `latitude`, and `longitude`. Then create an array of that struct and iterate through it. Having 4 separate arrays for values that actually go together is probably poor design.

Comment: haha yeah, I realized after looking at it for a while that it was poorly written, but it looked well-organized...But thank you so much!